# FileNotFoundException while showing the image from the local storage

Tags: android, filenotfoundexception, android-bitmap

I am trying to show the image from my download folder for that i am using this.

```
    Bitmap bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("file:/storage/sdcard0/download/13448FILE.jpg");
    message_image.setImageBitmap(bmImg);
```

but while doing that i getting the exception i already check this path the image is located there.I already given the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission in manifest

Log cat

> E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream:
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: /file:/storage/sdcard0/13448FILE.jpg:
>   open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: change `file:/` to `file://`

Comment: Thanks brother i try this but it not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, `decodeFile()` does not use a scheme. You would need to remove `file:`.

Second, do not harcode paths, outside of lightweight testing. Your path is wrong on many Android devices.

Third, do not decode images on the main application thread, as you appear to be doing here. There are many [image loading libraries for Android](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/46) that can safely decode the image on a background thread, loading it into your `ImageView` when it is ready.

Comment: Thank's a lot its work after removing "file:" . yes you are right i try to keep all three points in my mind and keep the changes what you have told to me.Thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 1):

uses this for get default path:

```
Bitmap bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/13448FILE.jpg");
```